# Choppy slow scrolling on iOS using jQuery Mobile

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, scroll

jQuery Mobile makes the scrolling slow in my app. I'm not sure where to look for errors. What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is most likely the `overflow-x: hidden` property.

Commenting out the `overflow-x` in the following like so:

```
.ui-mobile .ui-page-active{display:block;overflow:visible;/*overflow-x:hidden*/}
```

Fixed the scrolling error for us.

Comment: Can vouch for this as well. Ctrl-f "overflow".

Comment: ...fun fact, this fix can ruin the background-color of certain divs and make them flow into each other. So specify the background color explicitly on each div, even on white...